# Why does not my recursive friend function work in VB6?

Tags: vb6, friend-function

I have a recursive function in VB6 and I want the function to be a friend function so I can't reach it from everywhere, but it does not work. It will only say that the object does not exists, if I change the function to a public function it will work. Why? Have I misunderstood how the friend function work or?

The code looks like this:

```
Friend Function TestFunction() As Boolean
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

  TestFunction= False

  If Me.Works Then
    TestFunction= True
  End If

  If TestFunction = False And Me.HaveChild = True Then
    Dim objClass
    For Each objClass In Me.colChild 
      If objClass.TestFunction = True Then 'I get the break here, due to missing object
        TestFunction = True
        Exit For
      End If
    Next
  End If

  Exit Function

ErrHandler:
  Call LogError()
End Function
```

If I just change the function to a public it will work, can someone explain why?

Comment: What is colChild? A collection of objects of the type in which TestFunction is defined?

Comment: Yes, it is a collection of the class object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not limited to recursion. Here's a minimal example which shows the same behavior without recursion.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim objClass
    Set objClass = Me
    ' OK
    objClass.TestPublicFunction
    ' Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method
    objClass.TestFriendFunction
    End
End Sub

Public Sub TestPublicFunction()
    MsgBox "In public!"
End Sub

Friend Sub TestFriendFunction()
    MsgBox "In friend!"
End Sub
```

The reason is that Friend properties and methods cannot be called on objects which are late-bound, even within the same project. See [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241725(v=vs.60).aspx):

> **Important** Because Friend members aren't part of an object's public
>   interface, they can't be accessed late bound — that is, through
>   variables declared As Object. To use Friend members, you must declare
>   variables with early binding — that is, As classname.

So, actually, you should be able to fix your code by declaring your for each loop iterator explicitly, instead of implicitly using a Variant.

```
Dim objClass As ClassName
For Each objClass In Me.colChild
```

Comment: Actually he's using an implicitly-created `Variant` there, not an `Object` - but there is little difference aside from the extra overhead.

Comment: Right, I've been in .net too long. Fixed.